# C printing issues

Tags: c

What I am trying to do is the user first enters the number of people that will be asked the question "What color was the mug NOT?", then whatever color they say tells the program the answer is not that color so at the end there will be one color left over which is the color of the mug. When I run this it outputs blank space. If I add the code "printf("HERE")" just to see where the code is getting to it always prints HERE then the correct answer color for example HERERed no matter where I put the printf. This only happens when I add in that code. I know it's not very efficient but help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    int quest= 0;
    scanf("%d", &quest);
    int color = 0;
    char strcol[6];
    int ret = 0;
    while(quest > 0){
        scanf("%s", strcol);
        ret = strcmp(strcol, "White");
        if(ret == 0){ //White = 14
            color = color + 1;
        }
        ret = strcmp(strcol, "Black");
        if(ret == 0){ //Black = 13
            color = color + 2;
        }
        ret = strcmp(strcol, "Blue");
        if(ret == 0){ //Blue = 12
            color = color + 3;
        }
        ret = strcmp(strcol, "Red");
        if(ret == 0){ //Red = 11
            color = color + 4;
        }
        ret = strcmp(strcol, "Yellow");
        if(ret == 0){ //Yellow = 10
            color = color + 5;
        }
        else{
            //ERROR
        }
        quest = quest - 1;
    }
    switch ( color ){
        case 14: //Output White
        printf("White");
        break;
        case 13: //Output Black
        printf("Black");
        break;
        case 12: //Output Blue
        printf("Blue");
        break;
        case 11: //Output Red
        printf("Red");
        break;
        case 10: //Output Yellow
        printf("Yellow");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it. Not sure how I fixed the original problem but I realized I had a logic error where it would add the number multiple times if they entered the same color multiple times. Switched the method of counting and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
printf("Here\n");
```

every time you want to print something, add `'\n'` at the end.

`'\n'`  means new line and does the same thing as the enter key when you write text.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum COLOR {
    WHITE=1, BLACK=2, BLUE=4, RED=8, YELLOW=16
};

int main() {
    int quest= 0;
    scanf("%d", &quest);
    int color = WHITE + BLACK + BLUE + RED + YELLOW;
    char strcol[7];

    while(quest > 0){
        puts("What color was the mug NOT?");
        scanf("%6s", strcol);
        if(strcmp(strcol, "White") == 0 && color & WHITE)
            color ^= WHITE;//or color -= WHITE;
        else if(strcmp(strcol, "Black") == 0 && color & BLACK)
            color ^= BLACK;
        else if(strcmp(strcol, "Blue") == 0 && color & BLUE)
            color ^= BLUE;
        else if(strcmp(strcol, "Red") == 0 && color & RED)
            color ^= RED;
        else if(strcmp(strcol, "Yellow") == 0 && color & YELLOW)
            color ^= YELLOW;
        else{
            //ERROR
        }
        quest -= 1;
    }
    puts("\nThe color of the mug...");
    switch ( color ){
    case WHITE:
        printf("White");
        break;
    case BLACK:
        printf("Black");
        break;
    case BLUE:
        printf("Blue");
        break;
    case RED:
        printf("Red");
        break;
    case YELLOW:
        printf("Yellow");
        break;
    default:
        if(color & WHITE)
            printf("White ");
        if(color & BLACK)
            printf("Black ");
        if(color & BLUE)
            printf("Blue ");
        if(color & RED)
            printf("Red ");
        if(color & YELLOW)
            printf("Yellow ");
    }
    puts("HERE");

    return 0;
}
```